# Why my "node-package" doesn't appear in my node_modules folder?

Tags: node.js, github, package

I added this in my package.json file:

```
"models-package": "git+https://<token_key>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<username>/models-package.git"
```

When I run `npm install`, it says:

```
npm ERR! code ELOCKVERIFY
npm ERR! Errors were found in your package-lock.json, run  npm install  to fix them.
npm ERR!     Missing: models-package@git+https://<token_key>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<username>/models-package.git

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     <path>
```

I don't know why my custom `models-package` is not set in my `node_modules` folder. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably because you didn't add this package through command line.
Try:

```
npm install --save git+https://<token_key>:x-oauth-basic@github.com/<username>/models-package.git
```

Comment: Thanks, I wrote the wrong key attribute to my `package.json` file.